# REST api - Updating a specific resource with PATCH without including the specific resource ID in the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api, http

I'm developing a REST API for managing company cars, where employees take cars, and go on rides.
Rides have a property called `isActive`.

When they finish a ride, the `isActive` property needs to be set to `false`.

How my API currently works is that the endpoint for finishing (
`PATCH` HTTP request) the rides  is `/api/v1/rides`.

The user sends the `PATCH` request with the JWT token, and the API determines from the HTTP context which user it is, finds the individual ride associated with the user, updates the `isActive` property to false, and updates a short comment of type `string` that the user inputs.

Is this acceptable?

Every source that I found states that the endpoint should look something like `/api/v1/rides/{rideId}`, but I don't understand why it would be necessary in this context, because it would require more work on the front-end side.

Comment: Well, every logic that you make up is based on your own scenario, you cannot generalize it to what everyone says. If it is doing your job, it is fine. But you should consider it in the long run, which way would be the most optimized one and which way you might get issues. If it still feels good, then I do not see why you should not do what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this acceptable?

Probably not

```
PATCH /api/v1/rides
```

is a request to change the `/api/v1/rides` resource; which is to say the same resource that you are asking for when you send a `GET /api/v1/rides` request.  If you are intending to modify some *other* resource instead, then the resource you intend to modify should be the target URI.

The potential problem is this: general purpose HTTP components think all resources understand requests the same way.  This is the REST "self descriptive messages" interface constraint at work.  When you advertise that your resource supports PATCH, my third party browser/spider/cache/proxy is allowed to assume that PATCH means the same thing for your resource that it does for every other resource on the web.

When something goes expensively wrong because your resource was using different semantics from what is standard, that's on you, not the client.

PATCH means "apply these changes to the resource identified by the target URI".  If you are intending the edits to be applied to some other resource, then you should be specifying that identifier instead.

If you are doing something non-standard, then you should probably use POST, rather than PATCH, as the method token in the request.  See [Fielding 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post):

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”